# Meaning of the essay topic: "CSR is no longer an initiative"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have been asked to write an essay on the topic: "CSR(Corporate Social Responsibility) is no longer an initiative". What does this phrase, 'no longer an initiative' mean?In other words, What does this essay topic mean? What do I have to write about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CorporateSpeak, an *initiative* is a newly undertaken corporate activity which the company wishes to represent as positively 'progressive' or 'innovative'. 'Social Responsibility' initiatives intended to represent corporations as sensitive and responsive to social issues have been increasingly frequent in corporate PR efforts since the 1990s.

To say that such efforts are no longer 'initiatives' means that they are now taken for granted and no longer regarded as particularly progressive or innovative. Here's another example, from a [2011 scholarly article](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev-publhealth-031210-101148) on the U.S. government's 'Healthy People Initiative' launched in 1979:

> We review here some of the major features of this national public health planning and monitoring story, particularly in its launch and first decade, and we speculate on why it has had such staying power and lessons that might be drawn from it for sustaining other public health initiatives or efforts to implement and institutionalize strategic planning processes. We refer to it here as an initiative, which it was when it was conceived and launched in the late 1970s, but it could be seen to have become institutionalized and **no longer an initiative** as it weathered and reinvented itself in successive administrations and decades.